# Assimp and RViz will not import .scene file

Tags: ros, moveit, planning-scene

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to load a collision object into my hydraulic arm's planning scene, but it doesn't work with the [pillar example provided for the baxter robot](http://sdk.rethinkrobotics.com/wiki/MoveIt_Tutorial):

```
[ WARN] [1412647012.600856139]: Assimp reports no scene in file:///home/controller/Downloads/baxter_pillar.scene
```

There is a `box.stl` from the [MoveIt! tutorial](http://moveit.ros.org/wiki/Environment_Representation/Rviz#STEP_3:_Save_the_scene_to_the_database) example that loads perfectly well.

Why is `Assimp` not loading these text scene files? All I want to do is have a cylinder that my robot is not allowed to collide with when executing a path.

Kind Regards
Bart

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194331/assimp-and-rviz-will-not-import-.scene-file/) by [bjem85](https://answers.ros.org/users/18596/bjem85/) on ROS Answers with karma: 163 on 2014-10-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think Assimp is only capable of loading 3D models in a number of 'standardised' formats (stl, obj, etc). I doubt `.scene` is one of those.

From the tutorial you linked (section "Introducing an environment representation for planning", emphasis mine):

> We will now create a scene object in a **text file** to be imported into our environment.

and:

> You can now import this scene from the **Scene Geometry** field selecting ***Import From Text***

Are you sure you clicked the *Import from text* button in the MoveIt RViz plugin, and not *Import File*?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bjem85](https://answers.ros.org/users/18596/bjem85/) on 2014-10-12**:
That was it. Out of interest how come there are two ways of importing the files?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-10-13**:
There are more, but in this case I'm guessing that there was a need to separate the import of a single *mesh*, versus a `.scene` file that may contain an entire world (although I don't think it was meant for that).